# metadata.name = POD=name - environment variable for statefulset - app-0 app-1

Tags: kubernetes, rancher

I am trying to get statefulset to put something like:
/bin/sh -c 'NODE_ID="${MY_POD_NAME#"app-"}' and with the 0/1 to override environment variable to place a value.

Basically for app-0 I want an environment variable for say, 123
app-1 has another set environment variable, 1234, and I'll use the new environment variables in the args to execute a file:
./pagekite --frontend=$(MY_POD_NAME):443 --keepalive=1 --insecure --service_on=http::b2b:80: (as an example)

Any help for this?

Comment: All the pods in a StatefulSet will get identical environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

While @Jonas is correct in saying that all pods will get the same environment variables, you can create environment variables whose values are populated dynamically based on the pod object. You can set environment variables for things like [the pod name](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/inject-data-application/environment-variable-expose-pod-information/), node name, IP address, etc.

```
  env:
    - name: MY_POD_NAME
      valueFrom:
        fieldRef:
          fieldPath: metadata.name
```